# Как добавить SVG в трей?

Tags: c#, winforms, svg

Приложение - WinForms. В трее есть иконка - использовал NotinfyIcon, но вот тут я столкнулся с проблемой качества иконок. Иконка - это файл с расширением ICO. Файлы с пиксельной графикой не идут в сравнении с векторной. Можно ли добавить в трей иконку с расширением SVG?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько известно из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.icon?view=netframework-3.5#System_Windows_Forms_NotifyIcon_Icon) стандартный `NotinfyIcon`, работает только со стандартными значками Windows. Поэтому SVG в него добавить нельзя.

Максимум, что могу посоветовать, поискать сторонние контролы с поддержкой SVG, если такие существуют.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как бы ничего нового я не узнал из него.